# Implementing AMQP protocol on arduino

Tags: arduino, amqp

How can I implement`AMQP` protocol on `Arduino`?

I haven't found any suitable library for that purpose, and I wonder how a simple `AMQP` send/receive can be implemented on `Arduino.`

Comment: I remembered seeing a conversation about that, no direct solution but check it out maybe you will find it useful: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/any-arduino-library-for-amqp-protocol/423378

Comment: @Nino Thanks. I've seen this one before. No solution for `AMQP` is provided there. It only suggests using RabitMQ's `MQTT` adapter, but nothing else about `AMQP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMQP is a rather heavy protocol stack to implement on the Arduino platform, the codec alone requires a rather significant amount of in memory work that likely will not be suitable for a tiny Arduino device.  There are other better options like MQTT that allow for simple codecs and client stacks vs the AMQP model.

You'd probably be able to implement something so say an ESP32 or other board that has more CPU power and available memory but even that'd be pushing it.  The overall level of work to squeeze the protocol stack into a tiny C library is probably to much to ask for most spare time contributors.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I know `AMQP` is somehow a complex protocol; however, it was chosen on my first considerations as a protocol for a project. I think I found some ways to make it happen, using external memories and other libraries, but nothing is completed yet.

Comment: Good luck, having implemented several AMQP clients and servers it seems a heavy lift for a Arduino but anything is possible with enough work.  Your session and link flow control are going to need to be very robust to prevent being overwhelmed.